# Find game matrix and optimal strategies for each player.

Tags: game-theory

A, B simultaneously show a number of fingers to each other (both hands implies 0-10), money(£) is awarded as follows:

$ \bullet $ If the number of extended fingers is equal, then no exchange

$ \bullet $ If the number of extended fingers between each player differs by two, the player with the lowest number of fingers gives £2 to the other player.

$ \bullet $ Otherwise the player with the lowest number of extended fingers receives £3 from the other player.

I began with A's payoff matrix with each row/column representing the choice of $\{0,1, ... , 10\}$ resulting in $11$ choices each:

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 3 & -2 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3\\
    -3 & 0 & 3 & -2 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3\\
    2 & -3 & 0 & 3 & -2 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3\\
    -3 & 2 & -3 & 0 & 3 & -2 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3\\
    -3 & -3 & 2 & -3 & 0 & 3 & -2 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3\\
    -3 & -3 & -3 & 2 & -3 & 0 & 3 & -2 & 3 & 3 & 3\\
    -3 & -3 & -3 & -3 & 2 & -3 & 0 & 3 & -2 & 3 & 3\\
    -3 & -3 & -3 & -3 & -3 & 2 & -3 & 0 & 3 & -2 & 3\\
    -3 & -3 & -3 & -3 & -3 & -3 & 2 & -3 & 0 & 3 & -2\\
    -3 & -3 & -3 & -3 & -3 & -3 & -3 & 2 & -3 & 0 & 3\\
    -3 & -3 & -3 & -3 & -3 & -3 & -3 & -3 & 2 & -3 & 0\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Luckily, I found that each $\{3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}$ were inferior to $\{0\}$ and $\{4\}$ was inferior to $\{1\}$, leaving simplified matrix with strategies $\{0, 1, 2\}$:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 3 & -2\\
    -3 & 0 & 3\\
    2 & -3 & 0\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

However, I wasn't able to find a nash equilibrium, and hence requesting to find optimal strategies for each player A, B.

Comment: The zero sum nature of the game at least implies that there is no pure strategy equilibrium.

Comment: @Arthur: How is that? E.g. Prisoners' Dilemma is zero-sum and has a pure-strategy equilibrium.

Comment: So the optimal stratagies are to choose uniformly with p=1/3 ?

Comment: @joriki PD is not zero sum, is it? Both players are better off in the (cooperate, cooperate) profile than in the (defect, defect) one.

Comment: @pegasus: You're right, of course, sorry, I was just confused.

Comment: Those are valid concerns. Zero sum, symmetric, where no row has largest entry on the diagonal. I left out a few details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a mixed-strategy equilibrium, each player must be indifferent among the pure strategies to which she assigns non-zero probability.

In the present case, if all three strategies are assigned non-zero probabilities, this leads to (with the probability for strategy $i$ denoted by $p_i$)

$$
0p_0+3p_1-2p_2=-3p_0+0p_1+3p_2=2p_0-3p_1+0p_2\;.
$$

Together with the normalization constraint $p_0+p_1+p_2=1$, this is a system of three linear equations in three variables. Equating the sum of the first and third expression to the second yields

$$
2p_0-2p_2=-3p_0+3p_2
$$

and thus $p_0=p_2$. Thus the second expression is $0$. (With hindsight, we could have concluded from the symmetry of the game that the expected value of each strategy is $0$.) Then either equation yields $p_1=\frac23p_0$, and normalization then implies $p_0=p_2=\frac38$ and $p_1=\frac14$. The fact that all three probabilities come out as non-zero shows that the assumption that they are all non-zero was self-consistent.

Comment: Nicely explained, I was nearly there. Cheers.